# How to compute the actual height of the text in a static control

Tags: windows, winapi

My simple Win32 DialogBox contains two static text controls (IDC_STATIC_TITLE and IDC_STATIC_SECONDARY), here's what it looks like in the resource editor:

[image]

At run time, the text first string is updated dynamically. Also, the font of the that text string is replaced such that it's bigger than the IDC_STATIC_SECONDARY string below it. The resulting text string might span a single line, two lines, or more.

I want the other static control holding the secondary text to be placed directly underneath the title string at run time.  However, my resulting attempt to re-position this control in the WM_INITDIALOG callback isn't working very well.  The second string is overlapping the first.  I thought I could use DrawText with DT_CALCRECT to compute the height of the primary text string and then move the secondary text string based on the result.  My code is coming up a bit short as seen here:

[image]

DrawText returns a RECT with coordinates `{top=42 bottom=74 left=19 right=461}` Subtracting bottom from top is "32".  That seems a little short. I suspect I'm not invoking the API correctly and/or an issue with the different mappings between logical and pixel units.

Here's the relevant ATL code.  The CMainWindow class just inherits from ATL's CDialogImpl class.

```
CMainWindow::CMainWindow():
_titleFont(NULL),
_secondaryFont(NULL)
{
    LOGFONT logfont = {};
    logfont.lfHeight = 30;
    _titleFont = CreateFontIndirect(&logfont);
}

LRESULT CMainWindow::OnInitDialog(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
{
    CString strTitle;
    RECT rectDrawText = {}, rectTitle={}, rectSecondary={};
    CWindow wndTitle = GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_TITLE);
    CWindow wndSecondary = GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_SECONDARY);

    this->GetDlgItemText(IDC_STATIC_TITLE, strTitle);

    wndTitle.SetFont(_titleFont);   // font created with Create

    wndTitle.GetWindowRect(&rectTitle);
    wndSecondary.GetWindowRect(&rectSecondary);
    ScreenToClient(&rectTitle);
    ScreenToClient(&rectSecondary);

    rectDrawText = rectTitle;
    DrawText(wndTitle.GetDC(), strTitle, strTitle.GetLength(), &rectDrawText, DT_CALCRECT|DT_WORDBREAK); // compute the actual size of the text

    UINT height = rectSecondary.bottom - rectSecondary.top;  // get the original height of the secondary text control
    rectSecondary.top = rectDrawText.bottom;                 // position it to be directly below the bottom of the title control
    rectSecondary.bottom = rectSecondary.top + height;       // add the height back
    wndSecondary.MoveWindow(&rectSecondary);

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try LPtoDP(wndTitle.GetDC(), &rectDrawText, 2)

Comment: @Nikerboker - I tried that.  It has no effect.  It returns true, but doesn't modify the rectangle passed in.

Comment: Did you check size of rectTitle? Maybe it must be converted to logical coordinates before DrawText call?

Comment: @Nikerboker - I found one bug. I was forgetting to call ScreenToClient after calling GetWindowRect.  That fixes the left alignment issues, but doesn't fix the y-coordinate positioning.  I amended my question above to show the new code and screenshot.  The bottom line is that DrawText is returning a RECT that is only 32 pixels in height.  It should be closer to 100.

Comment: I actually can't tell from the docs if `lpRect->bottom` is supposed to be modified. Have you tried using the return value of `DrawText()` instead, which is advertised as being the height of the text that would be drawn?

Comment: @andlabs - DrawText does indeed modify the rectangle passed in.  rectDrawText passed into DrawText is initially `{top=11 bottom=143 left=11 right=454}`  On return it's `{top=11 bottom=43 left=11 right=453}`

Comment: @andlabs - The return value from DrawText is also 32 (consistent with rect.bottom-rect.top returned from DrawText).  Now here's the strange part - if I comment out the SetFont call, then DrawText still returns 32 and the same rectangle. It's like DrawText isn't taking the font into account. I even did a `SelectObject(wndTitle.GetDC(), _titleFont)` call before DrawText just to make sure.

Comment: The DC returned by `wndTitle.GetDC()` is different each time. You need to save that to a variable somewhere, use that variable, and then call `ReleaseDC()` (not sure what the MFC equivalent is) when done. And yes, you need to select the window font into the DC each time (as far as I can tell, anyway).

Comment: @andlabs - Thank you.  Probably solved. If you write that up as an answer, I'll definitely accept it.

Comment: "Probably" solved? Does your control positioning work now, or is there still some other issue?

Comment: LOL - I meant to say, "problem is solved".  It works now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite what its name may make it sound like, `wndTitle.GetDC()` doesn't return some pointer/reference that's part of the CWindow and that's the same every call. Instead, it retrieves a brand new device context for the window each time. (It's basically a thin wrapper for the `GetDC()` Windows API call, right down to returning an `HDC` instead of the MFC equivalent.)

This device context, despite being associated with the window, is loaded with default parameters, including the default font (which IIRC is [that old "System" font from the 16-bit days (most of this screenshot)](http://images.granneman.com/tech-history/windows_3.1_screenshot.gif)).

So what you need to do is:

1. Call `wndTitle.GetDC()` to get the `HDC`.
2. Call `SelectObject()` to select the correct window font in (you can use `WM_GETFONT` to get this; not sure if MFC has a wrapper function for it), saving the return value, the previous font, for step 4
3. Call `DrawText()`
4. Call `SelectObject()` to [select the previous font back in](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/06/10399678.aspx)
5. Call `wndTitle.ReleaseDC()` to state that you are finished using the `HDC`

More details are on [the MSDN page for CWindow::GetDC()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb9ztt3y.aspx).

Comment: In step 2 there is a function in MFC called `CWnd::GetFont()`.  This helped me.  Thanks.